# Yahoo boss: OAuth oauth_problem

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-authentication

I'm trying to browse the yahoo boss libraries from Firefox I pass the application key the response is always

```
<yahoo:error xml:lang="en-US">
<yahoo:description>
Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem="unable_to_determine_oauth_type", realm="yahooapis.com"
</yahoo:description>
</yahoo:error>
```

here is the URL I'm requesting:

http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/images/v1/Bones?format=xml&count=10&appid="my_app_key"

I hope somebody helps me to figure out what is the reason for returning this message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the old BOSS V1 service which is now deprecated. I recommend you check out the new BOSS V2 api here http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/. You will need to create a new key for the service.

Also, you will need to change your code to use oAuth and slight change in parameters.

regards,

BOSS Team